# Best program for making app for mobile (android, iphone and others)

Tags: extjs, appcelerator-mobile, appmobi

i try for a few time now to make app for mobiles with appmobi XDK phoneGap XDK from appmobi, sencha and appcelerator but except iphone where the app works ok in android mobiles doesn't work well. Any other program except these or any tricks for make it work better in android and in others?

any help it will be very important

thanks

---

Actually i want to avoid that.I want to build for all mobiles together in the same time.That's why i used that programs. I don't known a lot of thinks and i am looking for a simple way to do that. I want a way which i can read about it on internet and i can find thinks because except jquery mobile i can't find for any other library. So did anyone known how i can find the best way that's my question.
thanks for your time and your answer.

Comment: To get a decent answer for your question you'll have to provide much more information on what your app does and why it doesn't work well.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you're asking for a "program" and then referring to some technologies/tools (Appcelerator, PhoneGap, etc).

Anyways, I've been developing cross-platform mobile applications in the last few months using Appcelerator for almost everything. However, they technology you'll choose also depends on your needs.

There are three kinds of mobile development these days:

1. **Native Mobile Development:** Using Objective-C (language) + X-Code for iOS and Java (language) + Android SDK for Android, etc. You can always choose something like Appcelerator if you're targeting multiple platforms, as you mentioned earlier. **Good for:** Performance, Native capabilities (using the camera, for example). **Recommended Tools:** [Titanium Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com).
2. **Mobile Web Development:** If you have only web skills (HTML/CSS/JavaScript) you can always make your web application mobile-compatible, using tools like jQuery Mobile or Sencha Touch. **Recommended Tools:** [jQuery Mobile](http://www.jquerymobile.com), [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch).
3. **Hybrid Mobile Development:** Using web technologies for your application (you'll be loading a web page), but using a native application (a web wrapper) for making the application Native (and distributable) across the Play Market or AppStore. **Recommended Tools:** [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com), [Trigger.io](http://www.trigger.io), or you can even use [Titanium Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com) and use a [Web View Component](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/The+WebView+Component)

### How you should take a decision?

- Do you need native capabilities (use the camera, accelerometer, etc)? If you, you need to go either native or hybrid.
- How many platforms do you plan to support? If it's only Android and iOS, then you can use either Appcelerator or make it native. If you're planning to support more platforms PhoneGap or a Web Application sounds more reliable.
- Do you plan to deliver your application through the AppStore/Play Market? Then you need to make it native/hybrid.

**Note/Recommendation:** By reading your question I noticed that you're really confused on mobile and programming stuff. Before going so far, you should take some time in reading more about overall development.

Comment: I am very new in this type of programming and i haven't use these tools before so i am trying to learn but i don't know where and what i have to read for more information if you have any recommendation about  useful site i will be thankful. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not exactly a program but what can be quite convinient(based on your application needs) is to make it a webapplication. Then you can use libraries such as Jquery mobile to adapt the website to the mobile platform as well as incorporate technologies only available on smartphones, such as swipe, orientationchange etc. Then you can make a simple Webviewer for androind and iphone which can be made seperately.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [Kendo UI](http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/overview/index.html)

kendo UI mobile have support for : iOS 3.0+, Android 2.0+ and BlackBerry touchscreen devices.

What i really liked about it is native-like UI experiences for end users automatically on same code base for different OS.

You can check [demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/tabstrip/index.html) , change OS  using OS SIMULATOR MODE

I am not associated with Kendo.